# Possible to add custom extensions to Bluemix delivery pipeline instance?

Tags: ibm-cloud, delivery-pipeline

I want to add custom extensions like Istanbul for code coverage, SonarQube for static code analysis, custom tool for technical debt calculation. Is it possible to add custom extensions to a Bluemix Delivery Pipeline instance?

Answer (score 0):

You can add Build Jobs using Ant, Maven or other supported scripting tools to invoke those other services. You can't extend the UI.